# Delete all lines, starting two lines after /pattern/

Tags: bash, sed

Imagine I have a file the following file:

```
drink
eat
XXX
pizza
blunzn
sushi
```

I would like to remove all lines from the file, starting with the third line after the pattern `XXX`, so the result should look like:

```
drink
eat
XXX
pizza
blunzn
```

Removing all lines after `XXX` is simple enough:

```
sed -e '/XXX/q' -i data.txt
```

However, I find it hard to skip a fixed number of lines after the pattern from deletion.

The best I came up with so far is:

```
 sed -e '/XXX/ { N; N; q }' -i data.txt
```

Is there something more elegant, than adding n * `N` (imagine, I would like to skip 50 lines)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/pattern/{:a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;q}' file
```

On encountering the required pattern, loop the required lines then quit.

For fifty lines following the required pattern, use:

```
sed '/pattern/{:a;N;s/\n/&/50;Ta;q}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use awk, with a variable `n` representing the number of lines to be printed after the one that matches`/XXX/`:

```
awk -v n=2 'seen && !n-- { exit } /XXX/ { seen = 1 } 1' file
```

`seen` is uninitialised (*false*) until the regex is matched, so `!n--` isn't evaluated. When the regex matches, `seen` is set to *true*.

When `seen` is *true*, both sides of the `&&` are evaluated, so `n` is decremented once per line. When `n` reaches `0`, `!n` becomes *true*, so the script exits.

The `1` at the end is always *true* so until the script exits, each line is printed.

Answer (score 1):

For sed, I can only come up with something a bit obscure that requires a GNU extension to addresses:

```
sed '1,/XXX/{/XXX/!b};/XXX/,+2b;d' infile
```

or, commented:

```
1,/XXX/ {      # From the first line until the pattern
    /XXX/! b   # Print (by skipping all commands), except when on pattern line
}
/XXX/,+2 b     # For pattern line and the following two, print by skipping commands
d              # Don't print line
```

The GNU extension is the `/pattern/,+N` addressing scheme.

The `/XXX/!` bit is required to avoid printing the pattern line twice.

Parameterized for number of lines after pattern:

```
n=2
sed "1,/XXX/{/XXX/"\!"b};/XXX/,+${n}b;d" infile
```

Requires odd escaping for the `!` to prevent interpretation as history expansion command.

If the input file is really long and processing (and not printing) the lines after the pattern plus the desired lines takes too long, we can flip this around and not print by default, then quit:

```
sed -n '1,/XXX/{/XXX/!{p;b}};/XXX/,+2{p;b};q' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n=3
csplit -s data.txt "/XXX/+${n}"
rm xx01
```

Your result is in `xx00`.  This breaks the file at pattern `XXX`, line offset `${n}`, into two files, `xx00` and `xx01`, the former of which contains what you want.  You can change the prefix and/or format of the output files.  If you have multiple `XXX`s it will generate more files though.

Answer (score 0):

Bash equivalent of [Tom Fenech's elegant awk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42005282/298607):

```
n=2
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    if [ $seen ] && ! ((n--)); then
        break
    fi
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^XXX ]]; then 
        seen=1
    fi  
    echo "$line"
done <file   >filtered
```