# How do I delete all lines from a file after (and including) a line that contains a defined string in a Bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm hacking about a text file in the middle of a Bash script (on an RPI3B+ with OSMC installed) and trying to crop a file at the first line that contains the text "BLAH DE BLAH" (deleting everything in the same file after and including the first line it finds that text on).

**For example (in the file filename.text):**

This is the first line

This is the second line

This is the third line containing "BLAH DE BLAH"

This is the fourth line

This is the fifth line

**Required output (in the file filename.text):**

This is the first line

This is the second line

I've tried to investigate awk and sed related posts, but I'm finding it all so confusing as I can't find anything that does exactly what I need (some split at certain line numbers, some from the command line not a bash script, some before and after certain strings)... and I'm stuck.  As you can see, I can't even work out how to format this post properly (my head hurts so much)!

Any help appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all lines, starting two lines after /pattern/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004843/delete-all-lines-starting-two-lines-after-pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like

```
sed '/BLAH DE BLAH/Q'
```

would do the job in GNU sed.

Comment: Thank you - works great - I had to add an -i and the filename to get it to write back to the file, but I'm guessing that would be obvious to anyone who's done anything like this before (i.e. not me :) )